# How to run Odoo's Docker image in port 80

Tags: docker, nginx, odoo

After installing Odoo's image using Docker in an ubuntu server, I am unable to use Odoo on port 80 instead of 8069. I have tried multiple approaches **without success** including:

- Installing nginx in the server and use as proxy to redirect 8069 to 80
- Editing odoo.conf file and added `xmlrpc_port = 80` so it runs on port 80
- Pasting `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8069` onto  rc.local
- Running odoo from start up in 80 port

Has anyone been able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

if you're running Odoo inside docker container, you can just map port `80` on the `host` to port `8069` inside the docker container using `-p` option:

`$ docker run -d -p 80:8069 odoo:12.0`

to test this you should run `netstat` command line.

`$ sudo netstat -antop | grep LISTEN | grep 80`

you should see something like this:

`tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      971/docker-proxy`

if you still have problems, then you should examine port security settings (e.g. `security groups` on AWS platform)